# Make and extrude a square in Blender

Tags: modeling, extrude

Attached is a photo of a model. I went to Add > Mesh > Circle. Then went to edit mode, selected all vertices and extruded up. I can achieve the same result by drawing a bezier circle and converting to mesh first. I want to to the exact same thing with a square (at first) and then other complex shapes made from just lines. I'm unable to do a square. I tries grease pencil but just doesn't do what I'd expect it to. When I convert it to a bezier curve there's it always misses an edge and hence isn't a full square and it doesn't extrude like this.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, do you mean you are unable to extrude up a square?

Comment: @moonboots do you see the circle in the image. The same thing but instead of a circle it should be a square. I cannot draw a square

Comment: so what about create a plane, delete the face only in order to keep the edges, then extrude on Z?

Comment: Yes, that works for a square but then I want to able to do that with any shape after that. Like a pentagon or a random curve

Comment: you need to do the same: draw the shape, either a curve (that you'll convert to mesh) or a mesh, then extrude up. For a pentagon create a 5 vertex circle, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood what you want to do exactly and I am really new to it but I would go as follow:

- create a cube with the heigh/thickness (Z axis) that you'd like
- edit mode, face selection
- Deletion of top and bottom faces of the cube

You should arrive to this, and can always manage your object thickness on the Z axis in Object Mode with your Scale option/cursor. On the picture I am on Edit Mode, Edge select.

[image]

From there on, I would add vertex on edges as followed:
[Add vertex on edges](http://%20Create%20vertex%20on%20a%20desired%20part%20of%20an%20edge%20-%20Blender%20Stack%20...https://blender.stackexchange.com%20%E2%80%BA%20questions%20%E2%80%BA%20create-ve...)

Like this you have a square bottom side and you can get more complex with the other top side.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. That works for a square, but what if want to do that with any random shape, a pentagon maybe or a pentagram or an irregular curve.

Comment: For pentagon, I would create it from a cylinder mesh with 5 Vertices. Then delete bottom/top faces. And work out one side.
Pentagram, I would create a hexagon (10 vertices) from the cylinder mesh. Delete top/bottom faces. Select with shift every other edges and move them around as I wish with the shrink/fatten tool + edit a side.

For irregular curve, I would start from an edited circle that I would extrude and then edit the other empty face. 

The best would be to be able to create two separate surfaces and them join them together. But this I don't really know how to do it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This would help out a lot.

Comment: You can make square, triangle, penta, hexa... all kind of these circular formations with Circle as well, you just need to set number of vertices to 3/4/5/... instead of 32 that are set by default